# One identifier for set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this two columns. One is filled with some data, second is null.

```
col1|col2
---------
null| 72
null| 72
null| 72
null| 33
null| 33
null| 12
null| 12
null| 55
null| 72
```

I want to generate values for col1 that will gather and group values from col2. So one value in col1 for the same values from col2.
Like for 72 I assigned 1, for 33 I assigned 2 etc...

```
col1|col2
---------
 1  | 72
 1  | 72
 1  | 72
 2  | 33
 2  | 33
 3  | 12
 3  | 12
 4  | 55
 1  | 72
```

I was trying with simple query as a begin bot I can't move forward.

```
update t1
    set t1.id = (select MAX(coalesce(t2.id, 0)) + 1 from tblTest t2) from tbltest t1
    where t1.id is null;
```

I'm using sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: Why the update statement you provide does not do any reference to col1 or col2?

Comment: I just stuck on query that could update col1 with unique values.

Comment: easy to use `Rank()` method

Comment: You need to provide some logic for this - you say *"Like for 72 I assigned 1, for 33 I assigned 2"*, but why? Why not assign 72 a col1 value of 72, and 33 a value of 33?

Comment: I made a dumb query that will give your highest value the nr 1 (or 2 if 1 already exists etc...) but you have to keep executing it until you have no more null values so not sure if it's going to be usefull, so i'll add it as a comment instead of an answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b621a/17

Comment: DENSE_RANK and RANK resolved my problem, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this for example using the `DENSE_RANK()` function.

See the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE #yourTable(col1 int, col2 int)

INSERT INTO #yourTable(col1,col2)
VALUES(null, 72),(null, 72),(null, 72),(null, 33),(null, 33),(null, 12),(null, 12),(null, 55),(null, 72)

SELECT *
FROM #yourTable

-- Your part:
UPDATE yt
SET col1 = numbering.number
FROM #yourTable yt
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by col2) as number
    FROM #yourTable
) numbering
    ON yt.col2 = numbering.col2

SELECT *
FROM #yourTable

DROP TABLE #yourTable
```

You need to specify a logic behind your numbering. As your missing these logic, I'll assume you want the numbering based on your col2 ordering.

Comment: You don't actually need to do the subquery and the join, you can simplify this to - `UPDATE t SET Col1 = t.Number FROM (SELECT Col1, Col2, Number = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Col2) FROM dbo.T) AS t;` - Updates to the subquery will cascade to the actual table - [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a64f6/3)

Comment: I've splitted it in simple parts so that the OP would understand what I do, as already mentioned in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
update t1
    set t1.col1 = t3.row
from tbltest t1
join(select 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2) AS Row
      ,col2
     from tbltest t2
    where t2.col1 is null) t3
on t1.col2=t3.col2
where t1.col1 is null
```

Comment: You have a logic error. Doubled where clause. ;-) I'll fixed it. You need to approve it. :-)